# React Router/Navigation is refreshing my page every time

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-navigation

I have router and navigation page like below.

```
      <Router>
         <Switch>
            <Route path="/reports" component={Reports} />
            <Route path="/line-monitoring" component={LineMonitoring} />
            <Route path="/device-management" component={DeviceManagement} />
            <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
      <Router>





            <NavLink onClick="" to="/" exact>Dashboard</NavLink>
            <NavLink onClick="" to="/device-management">Device Management</NavLink>
            <NavLink onClick="" to="/line-monitoring">Line Monitoring</NavLink>
            <NavLink onClick="" to="/reports">Reports</NavLink>
```

Problem is whenever I click on header navigation entire page is refreshing. How can I avoid it.

Comment: have you tried to use `Link` instead of `NavLink`?

Comment: Yes I tried both

Comment: can you share some more code that you used <Router> and <NavLink>?
it is difficult to find the reason with this code

Comment: Nothing after that I have app.js with browser route. These two components included.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the `shouldComponentUpdate` method ?
If you wrapped your comonent with the `withRouter` method it will rerender each time you change the `location` prop

Comment: Can you please add code. I cant understand what I can add inside shouldComponentUpdate. And I used <Router> I did not use 'withRouter'

Comment: Don't you used `withRouter` when you exported your component that is re rendering ?
Can you please add some code ? At least the component that is rerendering.
It would be easier to solve your issue.

Comment: No I didnt use. Can you please tell me, where I need to use.. And how its helpful

Comment: Read this, it will help you : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/  Without your code, i can't do anything more